# Reading an continuously updating list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

My aim is to read values from a list in python which is continuously being updated by another process and I have tried to make a minimal working code here.
I have a global array defined in `cfg.py` as

```
def initialize():
    global infrared_frames
    global depth_frames
    infrared_frames = []
    depth_frames = []
```

and from `main.py`, one thread appends a random value in this array, while the main thread sleeps for 10 seconds and then reads the value from this array. Here is the code -

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import random
import time
import cfg

cfg.initialize()

def update_array():
    while True:
        cfg.infrared_frames.append(random.random())

p1 = Process(target=update_array)
p1.start()
time.sleep(10)
print('starting to read array')
print(cfg.infrared_frames)
for a in cfg.infrared_frames:
    print(a)
```

Unfortunately, when I try to print the array before the loop and after the `time.sleep()` call, the array is still empty but `p1` process is running. Why  am I not able to read the array?
Sorry if this is an easy question, my knowledge is limited when it comes to threading in python
Thanks in advance.
T

Comment: It is advisable to use a `Queue` for this kind of work. Create a `Queue` to which you send the jobs and create a `Queue` from which you read the solutions. [SimpleQueue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.SimpleQueue) is already provided by the multiprocessing package.

Comment: This isn't *threading*. This is multiprocessing. The separate processes *do not share state*.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @juanpa.arrivillaga, I meant multiprocessing only, will change it.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Thymen, I will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good approach for adding and using data in multiprocessing is by using a `Queue`.

A minimal working example:

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

from multiprocessing.queues import Queue


def fill_queue(queue):
    """ Endless process that fills the queue"""
    task = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        queue.put(task)
        print(f"Added task {task}")
        task += 1


def read_queue(queue):
    """ Endless process that reads from the queue """
    while True:
        if queue.empty():
            time.sleep(0.2)
        else:
            print(f"Handling task: {queue.get()}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = Queue(maxsize=-1, ctx=mp.get_context())
    task_fill_queue = mp.Process(target=fill_queue, args=(queue,))
    task_fill_queue.start()

    read_queue(queue)
```

#### Explanation

The `fill_queue` function keeps adding data to the queue every second. This is then handled by the `read_queue` function. It will check the queue every 0.2 seconds for a new item.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Thymen, this is an amazing solution and a lucid explanation.

Comment: Please put it as the selected answer if it solved your problem, so people know it is solved.